# User Meta option and hooks not working for Gravity Form User Registration Addon

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, user-registration

I'm using the Gravityforms User Registration, https://www.gravityforms.com/add-ons/user-registration/ plugin to create a custom registration form. And this form is linked to a woocommerce product using Woocommerce gravityforms product addons, https://woocommerce.com/products/gravity-forms-add-ons/ plugin. I need to update a user meta field using a field value from this gravity form for the newly registered user. For this, I have selected the required User Meta options from the gravity form settings in *Forms -> User Registrations*. 
After purchasing the related woocommerce product after filling this gravity form on it, the user is creating successfully. However, the selected user meta for this new user is found to be not added.

Tried to add the same using the following hooks available with Gravity Form User Registration Addon within our custom plugin.

- gform_user_registered
  https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_user_registered
- gform_after_submission
  https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_after_submission/

However, all the above hooks were found to be not working.

Comment: The User Meta option in Gravity Form User Registration got worked after updating Gravity form plugin and its addons to latest versions. But hooks are still not working.